# Combine the first two commits of a Git repository?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history

Suppose you have a history containing the three commits *A, B* and *C*:

```
A-B-C
```

I would like to combine the two commits *A* and *B* to one commit *AB*:

```
AB-C
```

I tried

```
git rebase -i A
```

which opens up my editor with the following contents:

```
pick e97a17b B
pick asd314f C
```

I change this to

```
squash e97a17b B
pick asd314f C
```

Then Git 1.6.0.4 says:

```
Cannot 'squash' without a previous commit
```

Is there a way or is this just impossible?

Comment: See also: [Edit the root commit in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119480/edit-the-root-commit-in-git).

Comment: See also: [Squash the first two commits in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598672/squash-the-first-two-commits-in-git).

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Use `git rebase -i --root`
as of Git [version 1.7.12](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.12.txt).

In the interactive rebase file, change the second line of commit *B* to *squash* and leave the other lines at *pick*:

```
pick f4202da A
squash bea708e B
pick a8c6abc C
```

This will combine the two commits *A* and *B* to one commit *AB*.

Found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9254257/105137).

Answer (score 127):

You tried:

```
git rebase -i A
```

It is possible to start like that if you continue with `edit` rather than `squash`:

```
edit e97a17b B
pick asd314f C
```

then run

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

Done.

Comment: If you are doing this to quietly fix a github gist, you'll have to add -m "initial" to the commit. ;-)

Comment: `git rebase --abort` to start over and do it the right way (not squashing the first commit in the editor)

Answer (score 70):

`A` was the initial commit, but now you want `B` to be the initial commit. git commits are whole trees, not diffs even if they are normally described and viewed in terms of the diff that they introduce.

This recipe works even if there are multiple commits between A and B, and B and C.

```bash
# Go back to the last commit that we want
# to form the initial commit (detach HEAD)
git checkout <sha1_for_B>

# reset the branch pointer to the initial commit,
# but leaving the index and working tree intact.
git reset --soft <sha1_for_A>

# amend the initial tree using the tree from 'B'
git commit --amend

# temporarily tag this new initial commit
# (or you could remember the new commit sha1 manually)
git tag tmp

# go back to the original branch (assume master for this example)
git checkout master

# Replay all the commits after B onto the new initial commit
git rebase --onto tmp <sha1_for_B>

# remove the temporary tag
git tag -d tmp
```

Comment: this triggers a massive interactive rebase when i do the `git rebase --onto tmp <sha1_for_B>`

Comment: Considering I had a brand new repo with only two commits (that I wanted to roll into one), this worked perfectly for me. Thank you @CB Bailey

Answer (score 14):

In the case that you have hundreds or thousands of commits, using [kostmo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21654379/456814) of

```
git rebase -i --root
```

can be impractical and slow, just due to the large number of commits that the rebase script has to process *twice*, once to generate the interactive rebase editor list (where you select what action to take for each commit), and once to actually execute the re-application of commits.

Here is an **alternative solution** that will avoid the time cost of generating the interactive rebase editor list *by not using an interactive rebase* in the first place. In this way, it's similar to [Charles Bailey's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/436530/456814). You simply create an *orphan branch* from the second commit, and then rebase all the descendant commits on top of it:

```bash
git checkout --orphan orphan <second-commit-sha>
git commit -m "Enter a commit message for the new root commit"
git rebase --onto orphan <second-commit-sha> master
```

### Documentation

- [git-checkout(1) Manual Page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)
- [git-rebase(1) Manual Page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Answer (score 10):

In the case of interactive rebase, you have to do it before A so that the list will be:

```
pick A
pick B
pick C
```

to become:

```
pick A
squash B
pick C
```

If A is the initial commit, you have to have a different initial commit before A. Git thinks in differences, it will work on the difference between (A and B) and (B and C). Hence the squash not working in your example.

Answer (score 1):

In a related question, I managed to come up with a different approach to the need of squashing against the first commit, which is, well, to make it the second one.

If you're interested: [git: how to insert a commit as the first, shifting all the others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645450/git-how-to-insert-a-commit-as-the-first-shifting-all-the-others)

Comment: Would it be better if the answer was repeated here too? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Git command for squad:
git rebase -i HEAD~[number of commits]

Lets say you have below git commit history:

pick 5152061 feat: Added support for saving image. (A)

pick 39c5a04 Fix: bug fixes. (B)

pick 839c6b3 fix: conflict resolved. (C)

Now you want to squash A and B to AB, perform below steps:

pick 5152061 feat: Added support for saving image. (A)

s 39c5a04 Fix: bug fixes. (B) 

pick 839c6b3 fix: conflict resolved. (C)

Note: for squashing commit we can use squash or s.
The end result will be:

pick 5152061 feat: Added support for saving image. (AB)

pick 839c6b3 fix: conflict resolved. (C)

Answer (score -1):

You have to perform a bit of command-line magic.

```
git checkout -b a A
git checkout B <files>
git commit --amend
git checkout master
git rebase a
```

That should leave you with a branch that has AB and C as commits.

Comment: Because the old and new initial commits have no common ancestor you may get some unnecessary conflicts as git tries to apply the whole history of master onto a, even though they have a tree in common. By using the --onto option to git rebase you can tell git the correct place to start applying.

Answer (score -1):

I'm also wondering what if the structure is like

```
X-Y------Z
 \-A-B-C/
```

and I want the final structure to be

```
X-Y-----Z
 \-AB-C/
```

In this case how do I combine A and B?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).