# delete first git commit

Tags: git, github

I made a mistake when I first committed.  I'm on another person's computer and pushed a version with their user.name instead of mine.  How can I delete this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git, but that involves history rewriting.

Comment: Deleting (or changing the author of) a commit that is the ancestor of other commits is inherently rewriting history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of duplicate questions related to this. The following is a generic solution for replacing the first commit of your tree. After you perform this step, you can make any other changes using `git rebase -i`.

[Insert a commit before the root commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645450/git-how-to-insert-a-commit-as-the-first-shifting-all-the-others)

Answer (score 4):

You can just force-push a repository containing the initial commit you want to Github using `git push --force`.

Comment: Great answer, did it in my case.