# How to delete first commit of a repo using github API?

Tags: git, github, github-api, git-plumbing

I know that it is possible to do using command line ([delete first git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430792/delete-first-git-commit))

But I'm not able to figure out how a similar thing can be done using github's API. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by "github's API", but if you delete any commit locally and push your changes to GitHub, the commit will be gone there as well.

**Warning:** Be aware that deleting an already pushed commit rewrites history and is thus very dangerous. Consider reverting/correcting your commit rather than deleting it.

Comment: That's what I meant by command line. It is explained pretty well if you follow the link I provided in my question. I'm working on a project that requires deleting the root commit from a repo using Github API.