# How to determine if git repository is empty

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check whether a git repository has any commits in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491832/how-can-i-check-whether-a-git-repository-has-any-commits-in-it)

Which is the best way to determine if repository is empty, like after it is just created?

Answer (score 4):

One quick way would be to look for files in the `.git/objects` directory. If there are none present then you know it must be brand new.

```
$> find .git/objects -type f | wc -l # if this prints 0, then it's brand spankin' new.
```

Comment: Does not quite work: rather count the number of commits