# Adding new roots in git (dropping history)

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In git, is there a simple way of introducing an unrelated branch to a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384325/in-git-is-there-a-simple-way-of-introducing-an-unrelated-branch-to-a-repository)

Let's say that I have two git branches. One with stable app (master) and one with new features (dev). Assume I want to drop history. However I would like to keep relation between master and dev, so that new git tree would be one commit with old master and one with dev changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `git checkout --orphan` suit your purposes?

Comment: It seems that git 1.7.1 that I'm forced to use doesn't support this feature. Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689960/how-do-i-create-a-commit-without-a-parent-in-git

Comment: Well, that question also provides a workaround.

Comment: OK, so last question. How can I make this new branch new master? (so that master would link to new master, and dev would link to new dev)

Comment: `git branch -f master` will force master to the current commit.

Comment: Will that also update origin/ branches?

Comment: You'll need to use `git push` to update the remote branches.

Comment: It seems that I can't: _To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the_

Comment: Use `git push --force origin master` to force the update.