# Creating GitHub Pages Repo

Tags: git, github

username.github.com/repo-name

**Instructions for setting up username.github.com/repo-name ***

```
cd /path/to/repo-name
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/gh-pages
rm .git/index
git clean -fdx
echo "My GitHub Page" > index.html
git add .
git commit -a -m "First pages commit"
git push origin gh-pages
```

I did this : **cd /path/to/repo-name**
After I did **git clean -fdx**, all my files got deleted. I had to download them from github.

Was this (**cd /path/to/repo-name**) meant to be on a new directory ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The commands that you are seeing are meant to [create an empty branch](http://schacon.github.com/gitbook/5_creating_new_empty_branches.html) `gh-pages`.

It is not meant to be a new directory, but a new branch, with no link to your master and other branches and add the github pages related content in there. It must have been done as a first step, but you might have done it after adding files, which might be fine. Read the instructions on the gh-pages wiki. It explains why the above commands were needed and also warns that you will lose the files, like you did - http://pages.github.com/

You can also use `git checkout --orphan gh-pages` as an alternative.

See my answer here: [How do I create a commit without a parent in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689960/how-do-i-create-a-commit-without-a-parent-in-git/5690048#5690048)