# What's the difference between "git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/gh-pages" and "git branch gh-pages"?

Tags: git, github

This is the process [given](http://pages.github.com/) to create a branch for GitHub Project Pages:

```
cd /path/to/repo-name
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/gh-pages
rm .git/index
git clean -fdx
echo "My GitHub Page" > index.html
git add .
git commit -a -m "First pages commit"
git push origin gh-pages
```

It states that `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/gh-pages` will create a new root branch.  I'm wondering what the difference between a root branch and a regular branch is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A "root branch" is one without a previous history. *

If you are at master and you do `git branch gh-pages`, gh-pages will be basedd off master.

Here, the intention is to create a branch for github pages, which is typically not associated with the history of your repo (master and other branches) and hence the usage of `git symbolic-ref`

Also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8815361/526535

`*` It is also called an orphan branch and `git checkout --orphan` will now do the same thing as the `git symbolic-ref` that was being done before

Also see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5690048/526535

Comment: What would be the problems if gh-pages branch is based off of master? would it change anything?

Answer (score 2):

The Git 223 (Q3 2019)+ version of that operation would be using [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch):

```
git switch --orphan gh-pages
```

> What would be the problems if `gh-pages` branch is based off of `master`?   would it change anything?

Then you would find all tracked files from `master` in `gh-pages`: you would have to remove them first before using your new branch

```
git switch -c gh-pagres master
git rm -r .
git commit -m "empty new branch"
```

Note that [since Sept. 2020](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-09-03-build-and-deploy-github-pages-from-any-branch/), repositories that use GitHub Pages can now build and deploy from any branch.

And [since Aug. 2022](https://github.blog/2022-08-10-github-pages-now-uses-actions-by-default/), GitHub Pages uses Actions by default, using a [starter workflow](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/tree/main/pages).