# `checkout -B` vs. `symbolic-ref`

Tags: git, git-checkout

Are the following commands equivalent? If not, what are the differences?

> `git checkout -B a_branch`

and

> `git branch -f a_branch HEAD`
>   `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/a_branch`

---

See also [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376142/checkout-reset-symbolic-ref).

Comment: From [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) it seems it is `branch + checkout`.

Comment: @Christoph: Is there a difference between `branch` + `checkout` and `branch` + `symbolic-ref`?

Comment: Good question. Does [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5690048/5784831) help?

Comment: @Christoph: It doesn't help, because I don't understand it. If you think it answers my question, maybe you can explain it more clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are extremely close, so much so that they might as well be identical.

#### You can stop here, the rest is because the above is a special case

They become much less close if you change one of them slightly.  Consider that you can use this as:

> `git checkout -B name commit-specifier`

as well as just:

> `git checkout -B name`

which effectively means:

> `git checkout -B name HEAD`

As [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) says, the `-b` and `-B` flags are the "transactional equivalent" of some alternative sequence of commands.  If those commands would (or do) fail somewhere along the way, the `-b` or `-B` action is *suppressed*.  And `git checkout commit-specifier` can in fact fail, when you have uncommitted changes that would be overwritten by checkout.

However, `git checkout HEAD` *should* never fail.  Given that it won't actually fail, the transactional nature of the `-B` operation becomes unimportant.  So now we look at what the documentation says this is the transactional-equivalent-of:

> ```
> $ git branch -f <branch> [<start point>]
> $ git checkout <branch>
> ```

We know that the start-point is `HEAD`, so:

> ```
> git branch -f a_branch HEAD
> ```

is correct: this matches the first command.  And, we know that `git checkout <the commit we are already on>` is essentially a no-op (does not change the index and work-tree) and `git checkout a_branch` ends up doing:

> ```
> git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/a_branch
> ```

as its final operation, so:

> ```
> git checkout -B a_branch
> ```

"means":

1. don't do anything to the index and work-tree (which succeeds);
2. if that succeeds (which it does), reset `a_branch` to the current commit; and
3. if that succeeds (which it does), make `HEAD` refer to `a_branch`.

If we add the starting point, though, step 1 may *fail*, and step 2, if run, does something different.

Comment: Thanks. You wrote: "we know that git checkout <the commit we are already on> is essentially a no-op (does not change the index and work-tree)". How do we know that?

Comment: We know it because `git checkout`'s first step in actually checking something out is to assess the up-to-three-way comparison of three items: "current commit" *C*, "new commit" *N*, and "index state" *I*. The index—that which is to go into the *next* commit—must be updated to go from *C* to *N*, so wherever those are different, something has to change. But if *N = C*, *nothing* has to change in *I*. That, in turn, means nothing has to change in the work-tree.

Comment: By the way, the rules for moving from *C* to *N* with *C ≠ N* then have to factor in a lot about *I*, including *I*-vs-work-tree; the exact rules are detailed in [the `git read-tree` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html), where *C* and *N* are called *H* and *M* instead.