# In Git, how do I create a commit that's before the oldest commit?

Tags: git

I have a Git repository whose oldest commit is version 6.8.2 (it is tagged "v6.8.2"). I have version 6.8.1 of the package that I would like to commit to the repository as the parent commit of the oldest commit. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Hakre, no. The repository is private and has no clones.

Comment: You could take back the 6.8.2 commit, make your 6.8.1 commit, then do your 6.8.2 commit on top of it and done - just rewriting the history. As you haven't pushed yet no problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: how to insert a commit as the first, shifting all the others?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645450/git-how-to-insert-a-commit-as-the-first-shifting-all-the-others)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could rebase your current branch on top of the oldest commit that you want (v6.8.1). It will rewrite your history, though, but it is possible.

**Edited to add more**

Assuming your code is on the branch `master`

Clear out the existing code and create a new branch. Your old code is not lost - it still exists on the master branch.

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/newbase
rm .git/index
git clean -dxf
```

Now you are on the branch `newbase` which is an empty directory. Add the files that you want to be the new base to here.

```
<add the files to the directory>
git add .
git commit -a -m "New base commit v6.8.1"
```

New you have two branches `master` which has your original code and `newbase` which has only your new base.

Now checkout the `master` branch and rebase it upon the `newbase` branch

```
git checkout master
git rebase newbase
```

And then All you need to do is fix the conflicts, and you have a new `master` branch that starts at the earlier state of the code.

This is all a bit of a mess though. If you just want to add the code to the repository, just do the first bit, which creates a new branch. Tag it so that you know what it is, there is no need to rebase the `master` branch on to it because if you get to the base of master, and want to go further back in time - you can just see what is in the other branch.

Comment: I don't see how because the repository doesn't contain a commit of version 6.8.1. My question is how to get a commit of that version into the repository and then how to make it the parent of the initial commit.

Comment: @Steve Emmerson - Updated now.