# git: solving conflicts caused by rebase

Tags: git, merge, conflict, rebase

because I did something really bad in the past, I have to insert an empty commit at beginning for a rebase. When doing the described steps of the solution (found here [Insert a commit before the root commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645450/git-how-to-insert-a-commit-as-the-first-shifting-all-the-others)) I struggle at the *rebase* command because of many merge-conflicts. Some are so complicated that it is almost impossible for me to solve them. Most of them have following structure:

```
--A---B---C--   B changes file 'foo.txt'
   \     /      D and E change file 'file.txt'
    D---E       git rebase tries to apply B on D (due to time stamp)..
```

When searching around, I found that git provides with rerere a tool for applying already solved conflicts. Unfortunately I did not know it before so it was not turned on. Is it possible to activate it and *scan* the history for resolutions? Or is there a different way to achieve the same result? Or do I have no other possibility than solving everything by hand?

Thanks in advance,

TiBo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, you're stuck with resolving conflicts by hand, unfortunately.  However. if you describe the original problem you're trying to solve, there may be a way to fix *that* without a rebase.