# git: change one line in file for the complete history

Tags: git, commit, git-amend

When I started my git repo I commited a few files as initial commit to it. Now, many commits later, I noticed that I included in those files a line with information which I do not want to publish (unlike the rest of the code). So I want to **remove/change this one line** and **keep the rest** of the code.

Searching around I found this solution: Insert an empty commit as initial commit (described here: [Insert a commit before the root commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645450/git-how-to-insert-a-commit-as-the-first-shifting-all-the-others)), do a rebase on it and then edit the old first commit via amend. Unfortunately, many cruel merge conflicts arise during rebase (as described here: [git: solving conflicts caused by rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194023/git-solving-conflicts-caused-by-rebase/7194301#7194301)).

Is there a different way to solve my problem or do have to rebase and edit all conflicts by hand?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you are just changing one line, the merge conflicts should be pretty small.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove sensitive files from git's history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/how-do-i-remove-sensitive-files-from-gits-history)

Comment: @Clueless: the conflicts do arise when rebasing, these are conflicts I solved in the past

Comment: @Karl Bielefeldt: I am asking about removing/replacing this line, not a complete file

Comment: @TiBo - It's too late now, but that's what rerere is for.

Comment: Thanks :) I know it now and will always keep it enabled :D

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Here's a command that will remove an offending line from a file's history in all your branches:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'sed -i "/sensitive information/ d" filename' -- --all
```

This checks out every revision, runs the `sed` command on it, then commits that revision back.

The `sed` command in this case matches any lines containing the pattern `sensitive information` in the file named `filename` and deletes those lines.

Note:  it's good if you have a backup, and try the `sed` script on its own first to make sure it's doing what you want, because it can take quite a while to run on a long history.

Comment: Is there any possibility to ignore a sed error (e.g. when a file does not exist in one revision)?

Comment: I don't know if the `-q` option does that or not.  You might have to wrap it in a shell if-then, like `if [ -e file ]; then sed...; fi`

Comment: If you know the commit the mistake was introduced, you can `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'sed -i "/sensitive information/ d" filename' <commit>..HEAD`

Comment: On windows I kept getting an error 'No such file or directory'. I eventually found out that using the full file path for the filename (eg: c:\filename.txt) and putting it in double quotes make it work.

Comment: And with a slightly modified `sed` command+args I used on macOS:
`git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'test -f yourfile.json && sed -i "" "s/oldText/newText/g" yourfile.json || echo "skipping file"' -- --all`

Comment: I had to use `--force` on the `filter-branch` command, otherwise the changes didn't appear to apply. GitHub [recommends](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/) it too.

Answer (score 8):

I made this command that doesn't error out when a file doesn't exist:

```
 filename=./path/to/your/filename
 filter=your_regex_here

 git filter-branch --tree-filter 'test -f $filename && sed -i.bak "/$filter/d" $filename  || echo “skipping file“' -- --all
```

Comment: Worked great for me. Thought I'd note in case anyone else runs into this -- don't remove the echo "skipping file" at the end. Otherwise you might get the error "tree filter failed"; since the last return code is non-zero git thinks there was a failure.

Answer (score 6):

My answer combines the best of everything. It replaces the just the given filter string instead of the whole line and it nicely skips if the file is not found in a commit. There are a lot of escaped quotes but the other answer had really weird quotes that didn't work for me.

```
 git filter-branch --tree-filter "test -f \"$filename\" && sed -i \"s/$filter//g\" \"$filename\" || echo \"skipping $filename\"" -- --all
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at `git filter-branch`

The examples in the link should get you going: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

Comment: I one found a solution for removing a complete file, but not for changing one line in it. Can give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Git history could be rewritten by the `bfg` tool.

```bash
brew install bfg

echo anyword0 >> words.txt
echo anyword1 >> words.txt

bfg --replace-text words.txt .git
```

More info here:
https://www.explainprogramming.com/git/deletion/