# git remove single line from file in git history

Tags: git, version-control, git-fetch

I accidentally committed a line of code that was not meant to be part of the commit.

```
class Engine {
    x: X
    protected _events: Event // <-- this line was accidentally included
    y: Y
```

the committed version needs to instead be

```
class Engine {
    x: X
    y: Y
```

I have already made more commits afterwards, so doing `git reset` and manually re-staging is not tenable.

Following [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7198036/12574341), I attempted this command

```bash
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'sed -i "/protected _events: Event/ d" src/engine/Engine.ts' -- --all
```

but receive the following error

```bash
WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history
         rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an
         alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo'
         (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.  See the
         filter-branch manual page for more details; to squelch this warning,
         set FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1.
Proceeding with filter-branch...

fatal: bad revision '_events:'
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Why not just do another commit with the line removed?

Comment: @AndyPreston because that still leaves the original commit with the unrelated line. I'm a proponent of [semantic commits](https://nitayneeman.com/posts/understanding-semantic-commit-messages-using-git-and-angular/); If I make a commit labeled `refactor`, then only changes involved in that refactor should be included in the commit- that's what the commit conceptually represented, so allowing unrelated changes to be included is disorganized/misleading/impure. When I `checkout` or review commits, the only changes that I should see are changes that were part of that commit's identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter-branch` for removing a line from a file on a commit? That's more than an overkill (not to bring up that upstream recommends to use `git filter-repo` instead of `filter-branch` these days... still a big overkill)

Just run `git rebase -i the-commit-i-want-to-change~` (make sure to use the pigtail!!!). Set the action for the first commit (which should be the one you want to modify) to `edit`. Save an exit. Git will stop on that commit. Modify the file and leave it the way you want it to be.

```
git add the-file
git commit --amend --no-edit
git rebase --continue
```

And now you have history the way you wanted. Disclaimer: I am assuming the branch you are working on a straight-line branch, at least past the commit you want to modify.