# Clean git repo on Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, repository, reset

The situation is as follows:

We have some project which persists on Github, and deploy it to Heroku, which has its own mini-Git. Some changes were applied directly to Heroku (cloned repository from Heroku, made changes and pushed). In a meanwhile the master branch on Github has gained also some changes.

Now when I want to push the main repository to Heroku, pushing fails because commits on Heroku are out of sync with local commits.

I do not want to merge with changes on Heroku - I just want them to vanish.

Is there some way to clean git repository on Heroku to push then my local repo from the very beginning?

I do not want to destroy application and recreate it again because it has some paid services and I am just an collaborator.

Comment: `heroku run bash` logs you into app folder then just delete everything

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can just use the `-f` flag in git (it's a standard git flag) to force the push.  See the side note in the Dev Center [Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) doc.  This will overwrite those changes you've made on Heroku obviously.

Answer (score 65):

Install the [Heroku Repo plugin](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo) and use it to reset the remote git repo.

First delete the git repo on the server:

```
> cd /my-project/
> heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
> heroku repo:reset
```

Then re-initialise your local git repo by deleting and recreating it:

```
> cd /my-project/
> rm -rf .git
> git init
> heroku git:remote -a <appname>
```

Where `<appname>` is name of your app in heroku.

The 2 repos (local and remote) should now be empty and in sync.

Answer (score 6):

Try going to https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo and using that plugin to remotely clean things up.

Answer (score 4):

If your Heroku push is failing because it's not a fast-forward commit, and you're not trying to do anything funky with your history, it's very simple:

1. Ensure that your non-Heroku repository is defined as a remote.
2. Fetch all remotes.
3. Merge your other repository into your local Heroku clone using the recursive strategy with the "theirs" strategy option.

   ```
   git merge -X theirs remotes/origin/master
   ```
4. Push with the `--force` option to make a non-fast-forward commit to your upstream Heroku repository.

On the other hand, if you're really trying to purge history, you have some other options.

- Remove all but the first commit from your history (easiest).

  ```
  git reset --hard $(git log --pretty=oneline | tail -n1 | cut -d ' ' -f1)
  git push --force
  ```
- Create an [empty master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/647451/1301972).
- Use [git-filter-branch](http://progit.org/book/ch6-4.html).

Personally, I'd recommend keeping your history and fixing the fast-forward issue as a best-practice, but you certainly have options if you want to modify your history aggressively. Git is very flexible in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

You can also simply use the heroku's app versioning system.
Going to "Activity" you have the complete history of the project: rollback to the first activity and the repo should be completely cleaned, coming back to its state when the app was originally created on Heroku.

Comment: That doesn't work: `! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)`

Comment: I don't know, this is a problem of Heroku that are they that have to solve. But... are you using the web interface or the command line? Try to use the web interface...