# Error message after successfully pushing to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

```
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: fata
error: error in sideband demultiplexer
```

This just randomly started showing up. My changes are being saved in git and pushing successfully to Heroku. I have no idea what this means or what caused it as I have not done anything new at all.

Comment: We're seeing the same thing in our Heroku deploys since today. All from build servers where we didn't change any deployment configuration. Think I'm gonna open a Heroku support issue for this one.

Comment: please let me know if you figure anything out. I am also starting to occasionally get strange errors were my push to heroku fails and then when I push it again it will work. example: `remote: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/master': ref refs/heads/master is at ae943f5f0b6bd283ds486ab6e9676ae973194a70a but expected 69e4ee4446428e4cef84756ff6381ae64e7ea1a24ff5c69`

Comment: The error messages disappeared today. I did not do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having spoken to Heroku support recently regarding this, you can pass the below environment variables when pushing to your Heroku remote to reveal more about what's going on:

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git push https://heroku:key@git.heroku.com/app-name.git develop:develop
```

Answer (score 37):

Just had this issue myself. What worked for me was this response directly from Heroku Support

```
$ Upgrade GIT on your local machine
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
$ heroku repo:reset -a <app-name>
$ git commit --allow-empty -m "Reset repo"
$ git push heroku master
```

Comment: Just the last 3 steps worked for me (reset and repush)

Comment: When I try running this I get `Warning: repo:reset is not a heroku command.`

Comment: I tried upgrading my heroku version and this didn't help. I'm using 7.39 from a couple weeks ago

Comment: MalcolmOcean - be sure to `heroku plugins:install heroku-repo` first

Comment: As an aside - for us it worked to simply reset the repo (`heroku repo:reset`) and then push from our CI tool again.

Comment: haha took me a year to get back to this but indeed I was missing the `heroku plugins:install heroku-repo` bit

Comment: The commit history will be gone. Isn't it bad?

Comment: @SmartManoj. No, only resets Heroku repo. Your GitHub/BitBucket/Local Git server will be unaffected, other than 1 empty commit added, needed to trick Heroku into deploy again.

Comment: What if one use only heroku git?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem on the server.
Your remote git server didn't reply with the expected git response.

First of all check your server `.bashrc` file. It might print error or there is a syntax problem with it.

Possible related questions:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/210381/git-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-ssh

[Git push results in fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314298/git-push-results-in-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-this)

[Strange error in gitlab: fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Depl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700988/strange-error-in-gitlab-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-depl)

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by Heroku and was apparently an error on their end.

Comment: This is not always the case - I would mark an answer that has some helpful content

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the heroku repo and then pushing again from scratch did the trick for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37925714

Comment: The commit history will be gone. Isn't it bad? –