# How do I remove Gradle Kotlin from Heroku, and deploy only fatJar?

Tags: heroku, kotlin, spark-java

I am using Kotlin / Spark Java Framework.

Deploying only fat JAR will improve startup time, because Procfile reads only the JAR, anyway. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-kotlin#define-a-procfile

And using Spark Java, not Spring, already mandates the need for fat JAR building (I think).

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to this: basically

- Remove the remote Heroku repo, using https://stackoverflow.com/a/37925714/9023855 (but don't recreate the Git)
- Remove Heroku/Gradle webpack; and add `heroku/JVM` buildpack
- Create [Shadow JAR](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) or Fat JAR
- Upload the `Procfile` and `*.jar` using (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-executable-jar-files)

  ```
  $ heroku deploy:jar build/libs/my-app-all.jar -i Procfile --app my-app
  ```