# How to add old zipped sources at the beginning of origin trunk?

Tags: git, version-control, repository

When I started with my simple project I didn't use any repository to store changes. I just created a backups with simple ZIP files. I have many of them like this:

- backup_1_added_feature_a.zip
- backup_2_added_feature_b.zip
- ...
- backup_N_added_feature_z.zip

At some point I switched to GIT. The first commit I made from my last ZIP sources, and I have already some new commits done:

```
origin/master: (C1)<-(C2)<-(C3) ...
```

( C1 == backup_N_added_feature_z.zip )

Now I would like to add my backup zip's in to the main trunk like this:

```
origin/master: (zip1)<-(zip2)<-(zip3) ... (zipN)<-(C1)<-(C2)<-(C3) ...
```

Is it possible in GIT?

Comment: You can just commit them and then use `git rebase` to reorder commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a manual way to do it.

```
git checkout --orphan newroot
git rm -rf .
# unzip zip1 to project directory
git add .
git commit  -m 'zip1'
# unzip zip2 to project directory
git add .
git commit  -m 'zip2'
...
git rebase --onto newroot --root master
git branch -d newroot
```

You can replace manual unpacking/adding/commiting of zip folder with a bash for loop, obviously.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/647451/2578489 for explanation.