# Create empty branch on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I want to create a new GitHub branch, called `release`.

This branch **needs to be empty**! However, there is an existing branch with x commits and I don't want to have its commit history.

The only method I found is to create a *local* `--orphan` branch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert a commit before the root commit in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645450/insert-a-commit-before-the-root-commit-in-git)

Comment: Everything you will make with git will be _local_ until you push it upstream to the GitHub server with `git push origin _branch_`.

Comment: One thing to note here: there is, technically, no such thing as an *empty branch*. What you want is an *orphan* branch with an *empty index*, which is what the accepted answer produces. This might seem like a pointless technical quibble, but in fact it's a very point-ful (if that's a word) technical quibble: Git's functionality is essentially nothing *but* technical quibbles, so you need to be very precise with your technical quibbling, when Git-ing.

Answer (score 703, accepted):

**November 2021 Update:** As of git version 2.27, you can now use the following command to create an empty branch with no history:

```bash
git switch --orphan <new branch>
```

Unlike `git checkout --orphan <new branch>`, this branch won't have any files from your current branch (save for those which git doesn't track).

This should be the preferred way to create empty branches with no prior history.

Once you actually have commits on this branch, it can be pushed to github via `git push -u origin <branch name>`:

```bash
git switch --orphan <new branch>
git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial commit on orphan branch"
git push -u origin <new branch>
```

---

**Original answer:**

What's wrong with the `--orphan` option? If you want a branch that is empty and have no history, this is the way to go...

```
git checkout --orphan empty-branch
```

Then you can remove all the files you'll have in the staging area (so that they don't get committed):

```
git rm -rf .
```

At this point you have an empty branch, on your machine.

Before you can push to GitHub (or any other Git repository), you will need at least one commit, even if it does not have any content on it (i.e. empty commit), as you cannot push an empty branch

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "root commit"
```

Finally, push it to the remote, and crack open a beer

```
git push origin empty-branch
```

Comment: Hi, after creating empty-branch github repository is not showing any file difference when i'm try to creating pull-request from other branch. Can you tell me how to resolve this.

Comment: @RaghavendraS See my answer. I had the same issue.

Comment: Perhaps some people are having an issue with this accepted answer because it is missing a `git add .` step after you have removed all files and before you commit?

Comment: `git rm -rf .` delete file from locals

Comment: the problem is that since its an orphan you cannot use it for a PR.   this basically doesn't answer the question:  how to make an empty branch *on github*, not in git.

Answer (score 29):

`--orphan` is good for creating an empty branch locally, however, in order to push it or interact with other branches, you will need a commit.

Creating a new commit on an orphan branch is not a good idea because you won't be able to interact with other branches. I.e.

```
git checkout --orphan test
git commit --allow-empty -m "init test branch"
git merge master
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Instead, you should prefer creating a new branch from the first commit of master. If the commit is not empty you can add an empty commit before the first one, as explained by @houtanb.

Answer (score 7):

You can also follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645450/insert-a-commit-before-the-root-commit-in-git) to create an empty commit at the root of your `master` branch. Then just create your `release` branch where that empty root commit is.

Answer (score 3):

**The accepted answer led me to some problems**, so I did this:

```
$ git branch
* staging
$ git branch master c74d99cf46f6ed23e742f2617e9908294b4a608b
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
```

And got what I wanted without and merge / pull-request issues. I just **had to pick a base commit to create my second branch** from.

Comment: If your branch has a base commit, by definition, it's not a _empty_ branch. What are the problem(s) you had when creating an orphan branch?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is indeed the way to go. However if you already have other branches that cannot be merged to de newly created fresh development branch, my personal favorite solution is to perform a rebase, execute the following on the branch that needs to merge to develop:

`git rebase develop`

That way the initial commit will be the first commit on the branch to merge as well. There is of course a caveat :) You are rewriting history on the branch by performing a rebase. So you will have to force push the branch to origin:

`git push -f`

Others that also use the branch, will be unable to pull now, so they will have to perform the rebase as well, locally, after fetching develop. Assuming they are on the branch that needs to be rebased:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/develop
```