# How to create a pull request on the entirety of a new Github repository

Tags: git, github, pull-request

How do you create a pull request of an entire repository for review?

Answer (score 8):

First, create a new branch called review. This just to be safe so that you don't accidentally clear master and your whole repository.

```
git checkout -b review
git push origin review
```

Create an orphan branch with no history.

```
git checkout --orphan empty
git rm -rf .
git commit --allow-empty -m "root commit"
git push origin empty
```

See [Create empty branch on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100048/create-empty-branch-on-github) for more information on creating an empty branch.

Now, if you go to Github and try to open a pull request from master into empty, you'll get the following error message:

> There isn’t anything to compare. empty and review are entirely different commit histories.

To fix this, you need to merge empty into review so that they share history.

```
git checkout review
git merge empty --allow-unrelated-histories
git push origin review
```

Now, you can create a pull request of review into empty in Github.