# Creating an empty file on GitHub

Tags: github

I'm searching for creating an empty branch on GitHub for 2 hours. I don't know how to create an empty branch in Git/GitHub. I'll be happy if you help me about this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jLPG.png)

As you can see in this photo, it does not let me create an empty branch.

Comment: I think a branch is, by definition, a copy of an existing branch that you then edit. Why do you want an empty branch? In theory, you could copy an existing branch and remove all the files, but that's seriously icky.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you right. Do you want a new branch which has no files? When you create the branch it will have the same content what the branch first commit has. But no problem, just delete all files on the new branch and create a new commit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create empty branch on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100048/create-empty-branch-on-github)

Comment: @redseven yeah, that's exactly what i want to do.

Comment: @kutschkem i'm looking at it right now. if I can make it, I'll let you know.

Comment: I solved the problem after @redseven told me what to do.