# git push to an empty branch deleted all my files

Tags: git, github, delete-directory

So my teammates had set up a git repository and all of us were supposed to push our own respective works to our own separate branch.

Difference is, everyone used the Desktop app while I tried to use the CLI to create a new empty branch and push to it but instead it deleted everything under my assets folder!!!!

I followed this to create an empty branch:
[Create empty branch on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100048/create-empty-branch-on-github) where in it says to use:

```
git switch --orphan <new branch>
```

which I did.

I initialised a new local git repository, set the remote origin, did the switch orphan command above, committed, and pushed. When I then went to check Github if the files are uploaded properly, I saw that it was only partially uploaded. Specifically, only the non-important files. I then got confused so I went back to check at my original files only to then find out that they're GONE.

Please somebody help.... That was a month's worth of tireless day to night work...

I'll include a log of the terminal here:
https://gist.github.com/NicholasSebastian/b5dceb995e5a33922df8fbeb99f03652

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: That gist is 10k lines long Please replace the gist with the relevant parts directly in the question. Also, don’t panic:`git reflog` is _probably_ all you need to look (and maybe add to the question if that doesn’t allow you to self-solve) to find your missing files

Comment: Was that Unity3D tag really necessary?

Comment: It looks like you are using _Git Large File System (LFS)_, an extension to Git for handling large files.   Since you used the command line, performing a `git pull` will **not** by default perform a `pull` of LFS files.   Just type in `git lfs pull`.   Also, since you **are** using Git LFS I highly recommend you use a Git GUI client as they will automatically handle all the LFS stuff for you.  This is vital when using a Git LFS repo with apps like Unity, Unreal, Photoshop etc.   If you don't, apps like Unity will think **you deleted stuff!**

Comment: _"That was a month's worth of tireless day to night work"_ - why did you wait a month to push your work to the remote?   I like to commit at the end of the day where my CI server checks that it can compile it and that I haven't forgotten to add something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after all that panicking, reading through a ton of git documentation and other blogs and sites revealed that I can list all changes on the git repository with:

```
git reflog
```

where it shows all the changes and its corresponding SHA reference values.

I can then use the `git reset --hard` command to replace the current directory with the state it was at a given SHA reference point:

```
git reset --hard <SHA value>
```

I'm glad I finally got all my files back at least after all that panic and stress.
Lesson learned the hard way: *Back up all your files.*

Comment: I haven’t used lfs, but I am very confident in git and that when committed, they’re 99% recoverable

Comment: Glad to hear you got all the files recovered.

Comment: @MickyD Thanks mate, you're the only one who tried to actually help. You're a real one.

Comment: No worries good sir.  +1