# Git Make new branch and push without history

Tags: git, git-branch

I have been trying to google for a solution but wasnt able to find exactly what I'm looking for, hence the new question.

I have a private git repo with only 1 branch (master) that has ~90 commits.

I want to create a new branch **public**, that points to another repo - which is public - but not want to show all the commits / history that master have, instead show only 1 commit like "Initial commit".

So far I was able to add a new remote, and set it to track the new branch, but when I push, it sends all the commits that master had.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to create a new branch locally. By default, this will use your current HEAD as a base.

#### Creating a branch without history

However, you can also create a new branch without any history using [`git checkout --orphan`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---orphanltnew-branchgt):

```bash
# create a new branch without a history and check it out
git checkout --orphan yournewbranch

# edit your files

# create a commit with these files
git add .
git commit
# push that commit and create the remote branch
git push -u your_remote yournewbranch
```

Alternatively, you can just create a new repository with that branch and push that:

```bash
git init -b yournewbranch
git add .
git commit
git remote add origin https://yourgitserver.com/your/repo
git push -u origin yournewbranch
```

#### Add branch from other repository locally

If you already have the remote branch and want to add it to your repository, you can just checkit out using `git checkout`:

```bash
git checkout -b yournewlocalbranch remotes/yourremote/remotebranchname
```

This assumes the new branch exists on the remote `yourremote` with the name `remotebranchname` and you want the branch to be named `yournewlocalbranch`

Comment: Ahh, perfect, the --orphan did the trick of what I was looking for ! thanks a lot, clearly thats what I was missing

Comment: The problem with this is that there is no return back to use git merge right? 
since unrelated histories, If I perform 2 commits back on the master branch I wont be able to merge them into the public one

Comment: No, you cannot merge unrelated histories. You might be able to use `cherry-pick` but merging unrelated histories doesn't work well - after all, it would create a new (merge) commit containing the histories of both sides until the common anchestor. You should decide for one history and use that.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is to squash commits.

Squashing commits essentially lets you simplify your repository by replacing multiple sequential commits with a single one.

How you can do it:

- You can just create a new branch (for example `public`).
- Switch into the branch using `git checkout <new_branch>`
- Then you can squash commits by using `git merge --squash <branch_you_want_squashed>`
- Then you commit the changes with a new commit message.
  `git commit -m "<your_commit_message>"`
- And finally you just push the changes using `git push`

If you want to learn more about squashing commits you can learn about it
[here.](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/git-squash)

Comment: That was what I was doing, but didnt work out as expected.
When I create public branch and checkout to it and run git merge --squash master it say "already up to date", and public branch still has all the history of master.

Comment: That's because the branch is being created based on the master. I might be wrong but I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100048/create-empty-branch-on-github) is the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a first commit, which corresponds to your "Initial Commit", then you can find it by running

```
git log --reverse
```

to see your commits in reverse order. Then, find the hash of the exact commit you want to branch out from and run

```
git checkout <yourhash>
```

and then

```
git branch <yourbranch>
```

You can also rewrite your git history, see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

If you just need a new empty branch, you can run

```
git checkout --orphan newroot
```

but don't forget to create an initial commit :)