# How to make a subfolder as a branch in my github repo

Tags: git, github

So,

I am current working on a fullstack project. The folder structure of the same looks like following.

```
/client
  /.next
  /app
  /components
  .
  .
  .
/server
  .
  .
  server.js
  . 
  .
```

I have initialized git in the top level folder from where I push to a remote github repo.
All fine till here.

but, now I have this final build .next folder ready and I want to push only the contents of this folder to a branch in the same repo. I cant figure out around this how to.

I have tried the following git codes

```
>git checkout gh-pages
>git add /client/.next
>git commit -m "Build"
>git push -u origin gh-pages
```

and, instead of only pushing the contents of the .next folder it pushed the whole root directory

Comment: And what happened when you executed those statements?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Instead of just pushing the contents of the .next folder it pushed the whole root directory.

Comment: _"make subfolder as a branch"_ doesn't make sense in git. A branch is a pointer to a commit, which itself is a snapshot of the _whole repo_.

Comment: Ah, what you want is probably a new branch that's *entirely unrelated* to your main branch. That's somewhat unusual, but is usually done for things like `gh-pages`. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100048/create-empty-branch-on-github).

Comment: @evolutionxbox then how what would be the roundabout solution for the same problem without branches. I read worktrees could solve this, but couldn't quite understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create empty branch on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100048/create-empty-branch-on-github)

Comment: @JoachimSauer I think --orphan would work. but what if I had to change branches in my workflow and then when I change back to this branch. would it still push only the .next folder?

Comment: Just switching between branches doesn't magically change either branch. The two branches will behave like any other two normal branches afterwards, except they will not have a shared common ancestor (which means for example that merge will decline to merge them by default).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Ohh! Does that mean creating a new branch using "git checkout" duplicates the current branch?

Comment: "duplicates" is the wrong word, but yes it does what you think. By default new branches are based on the current commit, so they "branch" the history at that point. Orphan branches are, as I said, a rather rare beast, as a git repository usually contains one thing/project and its history through time.

Comment: *"I have initialized git in the top level folder"* - this means that repository will track content of this top level folder. If you want to tack content of some other folder then you'll need to create a separate repository.