# Git committing old code

Tags: git, version-control

Is there any way to push old code to git in a way that makes it look old? Suppose I start a git repo with my  current code base, thinking I don't care about (or maybe don't have) older revisions of the code. At some future point, I realize I want to include some older version in the repo. I know I can branch, and just put the older code there, but is there any way to make it appear that the older code actually came before the original commit?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: You can just rebase the "newer" code on top of the "older" code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert a commit before the root commit in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645450/insert-a-commit-before-the-root-commit-in-git)

Comment: The possible solution if say on GitHub would be to fork the project and rename it using a version.