# Insert a commit before the root commit in Git + without changing the commits hash

Tags: git, hash, commit, rebase

[Similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645450/insert-a-commit-before-the-root-commit-in-git)

How can I insert a commit before the root commit in Git **without changing the commits hash?** - Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. Your current root commit (which would now be your 2nd commit) might keep *all* the information the same (tree, author, committer, assuming you can keep the dates).... but it will have a different piece of information: ***a parent***. This forces a new sha1 ID for the revision object.