# Insert a NON-EMPTY commit before the root commit in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, rebase, git-rebase

I have a problem, please be kind enough to advise! I have an existing git repo, and for various reasons(that I wont go into here), I am trying to create a ROOT commit

Say this is my git commit history:

```
(ROOT) C1 <-C2 <-C3 <-C4 <-C5   <--branchname (HEAD)
```

I want to add an initial commit (CX, which is not empty) BEFORE C1. So it should end up like this:

```
(NEW ROOT) CX-C1 <-C2 <-C3 <-C4 <-C5   <--branchname (HEAD)
```

I found a similar question here: [Insert a commit before the root commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645450/insert-a-commit-before-the-root-commit-in-git)
But it's for appending an EMPTY git commit before the existing root. 
I also tried the steps in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736098/11491070
with one change: I replaced `git commit --allow-empty -m 'initial'` with `git add .; git commit -m "initial laravel commit"; git push;` and then this rebase step: `git rebase --onto newroot --root master` is failing with a TON of merge conflicts:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: add initial quickadminpanel, with admin intrface and APIs for tags. Also added (but not yet enabled) ajax datatables module
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
.git/rebase-apply/patch:4537: trailing whitespace.
     * 
.git/rebase-apply/patch:4539: trailing whitespace.
     * 
.git/rebase-apply/patch:4547: trailing whitespace.
     * 
warning: 3 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in webpack.mix.js
Auto-merging webpack.mix.js
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in routes/web.php
Auto-merging routes/web.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in routes/api.php
Auto-merging routes/api.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in resources/views/welcome.blade.php
Auto-merging resources/views/welcome.blade.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in resources/sass/app.scss
Auto-merging resources/sass/app.scss
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in resources/sass/_variables.scss
Auto-merging resources/sass/_variables.scss
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in resources/lang/en/validation.php
Auto-merging resources/lang/en/validation.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in resources/lang/en/passwords.php
Auto-merging resources/lang/en/passwords.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in resources/lang/en/pagination.php
Auto-merging resources/lang/en/pagination.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in resources/lang/en/auth.php
Auto-merging resources/lang/en/auth.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in resources/js/bootstrap.js
Auto-merging resources/js/bootstrap.js
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in resources/js/app.js
Auto-merging resources/js/app.js
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in package.json
Auto-merging package.json
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php
Auto-merging database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in database/migrations/2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php
Auto-merging database/migrations/2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in database/factories/UserFactory.php
Auto-merging database/factories/UserFactory.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in database/.gitignore
Auto-merging database/.gitignore
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in config/services.php
Auto-merging config/services.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in config/logging.php
Auto-merging config/logging.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in config/database.php
Auto-merging config/database.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in config/cache.php
Auto-merging config/cache.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in config/broadcasting.php
Auto-merging config/broadcasting.php
```

How can I fix this problem? Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a side note: you've drawn your repository forwards.  Git does them backwards.  Put the root commit *last*, i.e., on the left, and the *latest* commit *first*, i.e., on the right:

```
C1 <-C2 <-C3 <-C4 <-C5   <--branchname
```

The branch name always holds the hash ID of the *latest* commit.  That's how Git knows which one *is* the latest.  Git uses `C5` to find `C4`, because commit `C5` itself, which has a unique hash ID, *contains* the unique hash ID of commit `C4`.  Meanwhile `C4` holds the hash ID of `C3`, and so on; `C2` holds the unique hash ID of `C1`, and `C1` *is* a root commit *because* it has no parent hash ID inside it.

Second, no commit can actually be changed.  So what you will do here is *not* "change commit `C1`"—neither you nor Git can do this—but rather, make a new commit, `C1'` or `C21` or whatever we want to call it.  Before this new commit we want another new commit, `CX`, that is a root commit and contains the desired content.

You *can* use the method in [Antony Hatchkins's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736098/1256452), but these days, the way to do that would be to start with `git checkout --orphan` (rather than tricky symbolic ref commands):

```
git checkout --orphan newroot
git rm -rf --cached .            # same as before
<arrange work tree as desired>   # same as before
git add .                        # or git add each file, same as before
git commit                       # same as before
```

That's the sequence of operations that creates commit `CX`, so that we have:

```
C1--C2--C3--C4--C5   <-- master

CX   <-- newroot
```

Now we get to the most interesting part.  Using `git rebase` is the wrong way to go *because* rebase works by cherry-picking.  This turns commit `C1` into a request to *add* every file—commit `C1`, being a root commit, gets compared to the [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452) to see what changed—and as you've seen, this results in an add/add conflict for every file you added in `C1` that is already in `CX`.

The question you must answer here—I cannot answer it for you—is: *What **content** do you want in your new copy of `C1` that is like `C1` except that it has `CX` as its parent?*  That is, in the end, we'll have:

```
C1--C2--C3--C4--C5    [abandoned]

CX--C1'-C2'-C3'-C4-C5'   <-- master
```

in our repository.  If I run `git checkout` on the hash ID of `C1'`, should I see the *same content* as if I run `git checkout` on the hash ID of `C1`?  The two commits will have different hash IDs, but the same author and committer and timestamp and log messages and so on.  If they should have the same *tree* (snapshot) too, the job is now pretty easy, using `git replace` and `git filter-branch`.  Here is the basic recipe:

```
git replace --graft <hash-of-C1> newroot
```

(and at this point you can run `git log` to make sure it looks right).  Then run:

```
git filter-branch -- master
```

(assuming you want only the commits reachable from `master` copied, and ref `master` updated).  The no-op filter-branch (no filters specified) copies each reachable commit, in the right (i.e., forwards, which is backwards to Git) order, copying `C1` first, then `C2`, and so on, but—crucially—*obeying the replacement directive*.  So now we have this:

```
C1--C2--C3--C4--C5    refs/original/refs/heads/master

CX   <-- refs/replace/<hash-of-C1>
  \
   C1'-C2'-C3'-C4-C5'   <-- master
```

If this is the desired final result, we now need only remove the `refs/original/` name, and the no-longer-useful `refs/replace/<hash-of-C1>` name:

```
git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master
git update-ref -d refs/replace/<hash-of-C1>
```

Your history is now rewritten.  All *old* clones must be destroyed (or at least, you should stop using them) because the hash IDs in them are those of the *original* commits, that you don't want to come back into your life to make that life miserable.  The abandoned C1-through-C5 in your updated clone are harmless: they can be left there, in their abandoned state, until Git's Grim <s>Reaper</s> Collector, `git gc`, gets around to garbage-collecting them.

Comment: @torek...omg you are a JEDI MASTER of git. This worked perfectly (even though half of what you said went over my head). I cannot thank you enough. Ps. I've updated the original question to show the correct commit sequence in my illustration). Thank you kindly!

Comment: @torek @kp123 At the point where `git filter-branch -- master` must be used, I always get the error `You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree.` – Any ideas why that is not working for me? I followed every step, only difference that I work on a "git clone" of my repo (before doing everything "productive").

Comment: @Oliver: run `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` and/or `git rev-parse --show-cdup` to see where you are with respect to the top level of the working tree for the repository you are in. I thought filter-branch was, at some point, adjusted so that it could run from a subdirectory, but perhaps not. (Filter-branch is officially deprecated already, in favor of the new filter-repo that's not distributed with Git, which is kind of a messy situation. You might want to obtain filter-repo and experiment with it though.)

Comment: @torek thank you!! I feel a bit dumb now, as I figured out the solution was to simply `cd ..` a dir level up to be literally in the git repo‘s root when firing the command ^^

Comment: This is indeed a jedi master-level solution! Incredible.

May you ealborate a bit more on the very last part about destroying clones & waiting for `git gc`: is there any possibility to actively destroy / remove the original `master`-branch & only leave my `newmaster`-branch with the rewritten history in place?

Tried force running `git gc --prune=now --aggressive` without any visible results locally.

Is the way to go to just push the `newmaster` to my orign & remove there the old `master`-branch there?

Comment: @Oliver: The basic problem—which is somewhat reduced in modern Git, but was a big deal back in the Git 1.5 to 1.7 days when I was managing a big company's Git repos—is that if you have an old clone that *hasn't* been filtered, and a new one that *has*, and someone uses `git pull` between them, you double up all the history you thought you'd gotten rid of. Git really likes to add "new" (to it) commits, and really hates to ditch outdated commits, so it's way too easy to get things back that you thought you were rid of.

Comment: @torek yes I see, experienced that behavior a few times while trying to get the history rewritten already. However, I am the owner of an open source project & got access to old versions from pre-git initial commit, that I want to add to the (new) history. We only have 2 collaborators in close exchange. What would you recommend to make sure the new „history“ is the single source of truth? Is there even a way for to do that based on your Jedi trick?

Comment: With just the two collaborators, manual cooperation is probably fine. It's basically just control over pull / merge operations that's needed.