# How can I create a new git branch from the base of the commit tree , which has no commit in common with master branch ? for gh-pages

Tags: git, github, github-pages, git-branch, git-branch-sculpting

**I want to make a new branch from the base of the master branch, such that the new branch has no commit the same as the master branch.**

> the new branch will be totally different from the master branch, and
> never to be merged to master

I want to do this because I want to create a `gh-pages` branch, to host my site. When I click on choose theme in GitHub settings, it creates such a dream branch. But how to create such a branch from the command line ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert a commit before the root commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645450/insert-a-commit-before-the-root-commit-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a completely empty branch you can use the orphan option of the git command:

```sh
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
```

Then you can add your commits and push the new branch to the repository. There are still [several ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645450/insert-a-commit-before-the-root-commit-in-git) that can be used. They are described here.

Comment: the orphan flag did my job, and the link you gave helped me learn more

Comment: Maybe you can tell us which error you get and we/I can help you.