# Squash commits without conflicts AKA a forced squash

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-commit, merge-conflict-resolution, squash

I've made a bunch of commits and I'm supposed to have only one. The most recent commit is the one I want to push but I need to squash it all down to one commit. When I try `rebase -i` I have to deal with tons of merge conflicts.

Is there anyway to just squash the commits into one message while keeping the code in the most recent commit?

Basically if there are conflicts I just want the most recent commit to win every time. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Are there merges in your history (like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133449/why-does-git-rebase-give-me-merge-conflicts-when-all-im-doing-is-squashing-comm)?

Comment: Why are you getting conflicts when you squash? This shouldn't happen if you're squashing a linear history.