# Why do I get a conflict with `git rebase -p`

Tags: git, rebase

I'm trying to understand how `git rebase` handles merges. I thought that with `-p`, it would be able to rebase conflicting merge that would have already been resolved. But it seams like it doesn't.

Here is an example to illustrate the issue:

```
git init
touch a && git add . && git commit -m 'first commit'
git branch b
git branch c
echo 'a' >> a && git add . && git commit -m a

git checkout b
echo 'b' >> a && git add . && git commit -m b

git checkout master
git merge b
echo ab > a
git add .
git commit

git checkout c
touch c && git add . && git commit -m c

git checkout master
git rebase -p c
```

Here I get a conflict applying the merge commit.
Can someone explain to me why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `-p` just keeps the merge commits in the history instead of flattening them. The docs explicitly say that this doesn't help with manual merging:

(from [the man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase))

> Merge conflict resolutions or manual amendments to merge commits are not preserved.

Comment: Nothing non-interactive that I can think of.  Maybe you can produce diffs yourself and re-apply them?

Comment: Thanks, just posted another question to understand why it behaves like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35714919/why-git-rebase-p-does-not-preserve-conflict-resolutions

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use [Git rere](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere):

```bash
git config --global rerere.enabled true
```

> The name stands for “reuse recorded resolution” and, as the name implies, it allows you to ask Git to remember how you’ve resolved a hunk conflict so that the next time it sees the same conflict, Git can resolve it for you automatically.