# Why `git rebase -p` does not preserve conflict resolutions?

Tags: git, rebase, preserve

Has the [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) states about `git rebase --preserve`:

> Merge conflict resolutions or manual amendments to merge commits are not preserved.

Is there any good reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be the same reason for the existence of the [command `git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) (**Re**use **re**corded **re**solution of conflicted merges)
See "[rerere your boat](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html)" and "[Fix conflicts only once with git rerere](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/fix-conflicts-only-once-with-git-rerere-7d116b2cec67#.3vui844dt)".

Git does not record merge conflict resolution for any merge (including the one done again during a `rebase -p`)

Basically, a conflict merge resolution is a *manual* step (meaning a human decision has to be made), which git is not able to reproduce automatically (it is, or rather was, a "stupid" content tracker after all).
Git is only able to record said resolution (if one activates `rerere` first)