# git rebase, squashing all commits: how can conflicts occur?

Tags: git, rebase, git-merge-conflict, squash

I have repo with a single branch and numerous commits.

I want to squash all commits into one.

I do:

`git rebase --root -i`

(see: [How to squash all git commits into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657017/how-to-squash-all-git-commits-into-one))

after setting all commits to squash (except the first, set to "pick") and exiting the editor, the interactive rebase stops and asks me to solve some conflicts.

I am quite confused about this. I understand conflicts when merging a branch into another. I do not understand it when squashing: should not be the newer commit be automatically considered as the "correct" version of the file ? Also, several files have been modified throughout the commits, how come only a very few of them show conflicts ?

Comment: Is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3143485/6577998) of some help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As hinted by @mnestorov's comment : you probably have merged branches in your history.

---

If your intention is to throw away a chunk of history and simply squash commits together, you can do so without using `git rebase`.

Just run `git reset --soft [target commit]`, followed by `git commit` or `git commit --amend`.

The first one will create a new commit on top of `[target commit]`, the second will rewrite `[target commit]` in place.

Comment: +1. This will also preserve, albeit hidden until gc (I think), branches and references, in case you need to go back before the reset.

Comment: Yes, and the reflog will keep the reference live and it won't be gc'ed until that drops off.  I don't recall the default time it keeps things, but it's like a month or three.

Comment: just for context : `git rebase` also updates the reflog, so the two options offer the same "you can roll back to what it was" feature.