# How do I clean git repo leaving only the latest snapshot?

Tags: git

Sometimes I clone git repo not for a development - but just for the bleeding edge version. Now I do it with

```
git clone --depth=1 <URL>
```

but back then I didn't know it. So I have some full repos - and I would like to leave only the latest shapshot in each of them. How this can be done?

**Edit**:

I think that if I will do

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git add .
git commit
```

I will lose the origin source - and would not be able to `git pull` later.

**Edit 2**:

Perhaps the simplest way is just to delete the repos and

```
git clone --depth=1 <URL>
```

them again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git squash all commits into a single commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657017/git-squash-all-commits-into-a-single-commit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, more simply, clone these repositories with the same `--depth=1`, and copy the remote repo's config (see `.git/config` file in old repo and copy relevant section to the one in your new repo.

Comment: i.e. `git clone --depth=1 /path/to/extant/repo newrepo && cd newrepo && cp /path/to/extant/repo/.git/config .git/config`