# Clear git log file

Tags: git, logging, delete-file

I want to clear the git log files so that the command `git log` returns nothing. Is this possible? Is this recommended?

Comment: Why is destroying your history a desired outcome?

Comment: The log is kind of the whole point to revision control.

Comment: Do you want to remove all your commits or do you want just remove the commit messages?

Comment: The way you do this if rm -rf .git, git init, git add --all

Answer (score 26):

```
      ______________________________    . \  | / .
     /                            / \     \ \ / /
    |                            | ==========  - -    WARNING!
     \____________________________\_/     / / \ \
  ______________________________      \  | / | \      THIS WILL DESTROY
 /                            / \     \ \ / /.   .    YOUR REPOSITORY!
|                            | ==========  - -
 \____________________________\_/     / / \ \    /
      ______________________________   / |\  | /  .
     /                            / \     \ \ / /
    |                            | ==========  -  - -
     \____________________________\_/     / / \ \
                                        .  / | \  .
```

`git log` displays the change history of your project.  If you really want to discard all of that history, you could...

```
rm -rf .git
git init
```

...but there are a relatively small number of situations where that really makes sense.

There aren't any "git log files" that git uses to produce this output; it is iterating over the database of objects that form the history of your project.  If you delete the `.git` directory like this, there's no going back:

- You will not be able to retrieve previous versions of files from the repository;
- You will not be able to see how files have changed over time;
- You will not be able to restore a file you have accidentally deleted.

Comment: You should probably make it clearer at the beginning that this will completely destroy the git repository (i.e. a bold text warning or something).

Comment: May be he wants to get rid of comments only? Removing .git is not a solution, there could be multiple branches, remotes, etc.. Your soluion destroys all of them.

Comment: Well, yes, and hopefully that's abundantly clear.  Or did you miss the warning?

Comment: I think that a use case for this could be something like this - you clone an example project, but you don't want the history of that project as you're going to use it as a scaffold. Thus, removing the entire git history and restarting could be logical. That said, I think this is the *only* use case where you'd want this.

Answer (score 5):

You might be looking for:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --aggressive --prune=all
```

The first line will prune all unreachable reflogs. The second line will do a number of housekeeping tasks, such as compressing file revisions and removing unreachable objects.

Comment: it seems that this only clears entries in the local copy of the repo; if you do a fresh git clone the entries will still be there

Comment: I did this and the output of `git log` looks unchanged. What am I missing?

Comment: @Gabe These two commands will not change the output of `git log`, because they will not touch reachable commits. These two command will result in a smalling repository. This can be verified with `du -sh .git` on Unix.

Answer (score 0):

basically what you want to do is delete the file containing the logs which is your ".git" file.

1. rm -rf .git  // this is saying remove recursively the git file.
2. git init    // this is making the folder a git repo again.