# GitHub - How to push a project on its latest stage, ignoring all old commits?

Tags: git, github, push, commit

I've a project that I want to push to github, but I want to push it on the actual stage without any older commit. How can I do it?

Edit. I've created a separet branch for it, so I want to push this branch without any other commit from the other branchs. I'm doing this because I've added a late gitignore and now all files in the git ignore are being versioned and to the purpose of this branch/repository is to review the actual code of a few folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little research, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543055/how-to-push-new-branch-without-history/12543340#12543340), where the author suggest to use the command `git checkout --orphan`, and that was exactly what I was looking for, with this command I could create a new branch, with no trace of history of the other branchs, this way I could push to the repository with only the files I needed to show.

I just did this steps:

```
// Created a new orphan branch
git commit --orphan <branchname>

// at this point I have edited all my files, and set the .gitignore
// cleared cached files, so I have no issues with .gitignore files
git rm --cached -r -f .

// added all files
git add .

// commited the changes
git commit -m 'new orphan branch'

// pushed to the repository
git push <repositoryname> <localbranchname>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the base of your branch:

```
git merge-base {baseBranch} HEAD
```

use a command to soft reset the branch back to before the first commit:

```
git reset --soft {hashOfCommitForYourBase}
git add .; git commit -m "my new message"
```

then push force:

```
git push --force
```

Comment: I'm using a separated branch, if I soft reset and move the head in the branch nothing will be changed on my main branch, right?

Comment: that's correct this command would only change the branch that you are working on

Comment: I'm getting an error saying there is no hash in the working tree if I use the hash given by the rev-list command, and if I use the first hash of the current branch nothing changes.

Comment: tested this idea a bit and problem was we were trying to reset before history began instead of a merge base commit. I edited it to use a merge base. You're going to want to use a commit that's a merge base for your eventual target.