# How do I squash all commits without losing submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I like the answers from [How to squash all git commits into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657017/squash-all-git-commits-into-a-single-commit).

However, I get merge conflicts if I:

```
git rebase --root -i
```

with pick and squash as suggested.

And, I lose my submodules (I have 5), when I

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git add .
```

What is the most effective way to squash all history and keep my submodules in their current directories at their current sha.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `git reset --soft SHAOFFIRSTCOMMIT` and then `git commit --amend`

The first command resets the current branch to the first commit, but keeps the current index and the second command commits the current index in the last commit.

Comment: No, `git reset --mixed` resets the index. (`--mixed` is the default, by the way.) `--soft` is the option to leave the index as it is.

Comment: but iirc mixed also does the job innthis case, right?

Comment: No, in general, it doesn't. After `git reset --mixed`, you'd have to worry about re-updating your index to the exact state it was in before you executed `git reset`, and that's not necessarily trivial.

Comment: This is brilliant.  I guess this would preserve peoples branches too.