# Squash all commit id's which were pushed before a commit (git rebase -i <after-this-commit-id>)

Tags: git

How to squash commits in git after they have been pushed?

I want to squash all commit id's which were pushed before a commit id (git rebase -i )

```
commit dc5aebdc5dc4a6b3fdcb95700d726de6ef489701

commit 83a1d881a28bcb894709ce538e08b3c0b4dd347c

commit 430269f03c57bdca9364f49ca2861652324a1593

commit 980269f03c57bdca9364f49ca2861652324a1534
```

For ex, In above log, I want to squash all commits which were pushed before
`dc5aebdc5dc4a6b3fdcb95700d726de6ef489701`.

i.e. `83a1d881a28bcb894709ce538e08b3c0b4dd347c`,`430269f03c57bdca9364f49ca2861652324a1593` & `980269f03c57bdca9364f49ca2861652324a1534` into one commit.

Comment: This seems like an unusual request.  Do you really want to squash _everything_ before a certain commit?  Can you elaborate on what your particular situation is?

Comment: I merged two different repo. In the new repo, I want to keep single commit for all commits from old repo i.e. indicating that till this commit, all were ported from old repo.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657017/how-to-squash-all-git-commits-into-one) looks very relevant to your problem.