# Is it possible to "forget" all the past of certain master commit and assume current one to be initial?

Tags: git

Say there is a sequence: `Commit 1 -> Commit 2 -> Commit 3`. I'd like to forget that `Commit 1` and `Commit 2` ever existed, such that `Commit 3` assumed to be a single existing commit, however all the changes made by both `Commit 1` and `Commit 2` are "backed-in" the `Commit 3`.

How can I achieve that?

P.S. It is going to be `master` branch, if this matters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to squash all git commits into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657017/how-to-squash-all-git-commits-into-one)

Comment: The fact that one question have the same answer than other doesn't mean they are duplicates. Your "possible duplicates" references question about how to do something that by the way is the solution to this problem. However there are more solutions, such as using checkout --orphan, that could not be the solution to those questions.

Comment: If those were exact duplicates then the eftshift0's answer should apply to them as well, but it is not always the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start over with a new branch with the working tree as you have it in front of you with `git checkout --orphan`

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if my answer is ideal or not, but the way i did is using

```
git rebase -i --root
```

after that, squash the second commit to the first commit. also don't forget to pick the 3rd commit. by edit the interactive rebase prompt in your console,

```
pick 3609c82 commit 1
squash 21d643a commit 2
pick 0ce4e9c commit 3

# Rebase 3da6375 onto db86c06 (3 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop = remove commit
```

save then exit,..

if there any conflict happen you can resolve and do "git rebase --continue". or you can also abort the rebase using "git rebase --abort"

you also can rename the the commit by using amend.

remember, always do backup before you changed any history like rebase squash or amend. because from what i understand, it is not revert/reset able. that's why i said, maybe this is not ideal, but that is what i did and it worked.

have a nice day!