# How to undo last git commit if it was the first one as well?

Tags: git

I am aware that we can undo like this : [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git)

However if the commit we want to undo is the first one in the project we got this error message:

```
git add file

git commit -m "first commit"

git reset HEAD~1
```

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~1': unknown revision or path not in
>   the working tree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to squash all git commits into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657017/how-to-squash-all-git-commits-into-one)

Comment: I try to always make the first commit in a new repository empty for this reason :-)

Comment: @oyvind: An initial commit consisting solely of a README and/or LICENSE file is pretty good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove  HEAD and restore your repository to a new state, where you can create a new initial commit:

```
git update-ref -d HEAD
```

After creating a new commit, if you have already pushed to the remote server, you will need to force it to the remote in order to overwrite the previous initial commit:

```
git push --force origin
```

Answer (score 1):

Reverting back your first commit is just like creating an empty git repo. Delete the .git folder and initiate a new one

Answer (score 1):

- Using `git update-ref -d` will revert the initial commit.
- Point to be noted here is it keeps all previously committed changes added to the
  index.
- In order to remove these changes,run `git reset --hard`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the working tree the way you want for the first revisión, add everything, then:

```
git commit --amend -m "first commit"
```

And then the old first commit is gone.