# Delete part of the commit history - git

Tags: git, github

I have cloned some template repo and start to develop my own project with this template, the problem is that all history commits of the template owners are still visible in my project commit history on github.

for example, now my commit history as below:

```
some_commit

I committed 11 minutes ago
 
some_commit

I committed 14 minutes ago

Commits on Dec 19, 2020
v2.0.1

@someowner
someowner committed 16 days ago

@someowner
someowner committed 16 days ago

@someowner
someowner committed 16 days ago

Commits on Sep 26, 2020
v1.3.1 (#2564) …

@owner2
@owner3
@owner4
3 people committed on Sep 26, 2020
```

what I want is in some way to merge up all owners commmits and show mine commits as starting point, like below:

```
some_commit

I committed 11 minutes ago
 
some_commit

I committed 14 minutes ago

Commits on Dec 19, 2020
v2.0.1

Starting point commit

I committed on Dec 19, 2020
```

I saw some past posts on this issue, but for some reason it effects my current code.

Comment: Was it actually a "template repo"? If so you can follow [these instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-repository-from-a-template) to create a new repo without the history, rather than forking.

Comment: @jonrsharpe there is an option to do this change without deleting and re-creating my project? because I have done alot of changes.

Comment: No, if you want to keep your current commits you'd have to squash - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1657017/3001761

Comment: And you'll retain your commits by squashing, but they'll all get new SHAs I believe, since their original parent changed SHA. I may stand corrected