# Rewrite git history to squash a bunch of old commits

Tags: git

I have  a git repository with ~6000 commits and 40 branches, which is a fork of previous repository with ~5000 commits.
Is it possible to squash all 5000 commits that came from original repo to a single "initial" commit, and rewrite the history of the new repository on top of it for all branches?

Comment: Yes! That is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to squash all git commits into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657017/how-to-squash-all-git-commits-into-one)

Comment: Thanks Brian, but using rebase this way or an orphan branch are actions on a given branch, and brake my other branches. I need to keep the recent history of all branches intact