# git rebase -i HEAD~5 and pull request with not mine commits

Tags: git, github

I just did git rebase -i HEAD~5, wanted to fixup/squash 2 of my commits... then had to force push and now my remote branch has one commit of mine and 4 of someone else. WTF. please help, how to remove the other 4 commits of someone's else?! I just want it to have that one commit of mine.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a diagram of the recent commits. Identify the ones you want to keep and the ones you want to remove, and also show one commit beyond that.

Comment: doing git rebase -i HEAD~5 again shows me a list of 9999 commits, do i need to stash every of them manually?!

Comment: That seems like a lot, and also a very interesting number. You really need to include some screenshots or otherwise share more information before we can help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git commits are duplicated in the same branch after doing a rebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264314/git-commits-are-duplicated-in-the-same-branch-after-doing-a-rebase)

Answer (score 1):

When you do a `git rebase -i HEAD~5` you also get all the commits in a merge.
You had a `merge commit` so you had more commits that the actual 5 commits.

For example:
here is the log screenshot + the `git rebase -i HEAD~5` which results in 17 commits.

You can follow the log and count the 5 commits on the most left branch and you will see that all the other commits are "collected" on the way as well.

[image]

Comment: how to get rid of that merge commits i got?

Comment: you can add the `--preserve-merges` but it will show all teh commits in range. `git rebase -i HEAD~5 --preserve-merges` as far as i know you cant avoid it since its a rebase with all of it sequences

Answer (score 1):

Managed to go back with `git reflog` and fix it from there.