# Git merging branch with duplicate commits

Tags: git, merge, rebase

This question is related to the following questions:

[Git: duplicate commits after local rebase, then pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462553/git-duplicate-commits-after-local-rebase-then-pull)

[Git commits are duplicated in the same branch after doing a rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264314/git-commits-are-duplicated-in-the-same-branch-after-doing-a-rebase)

I created a new branch named seebuild out of my development branch. The mistake I made was that I rebased commits (A and B)  in seebuild branch which were already pushed in develop branch. Now I end up duplicate commits in seebuild. When I now try to merge seebuild into develop, I get conflicts. The picture shows the scenario[image]

Now I donot need to retain my seebuild and origin/seebuild and these branches can be deleted after merging them in develop branch. But I must merge commits C and D in develop branch and while doing so I want to exclude the duplicate commits A and B. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the history of their branch you can [cherry pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) them in with `git cherry-pick`