# How can I find out who force pushed in git?

Tags: git, push, blame

Someone used `git push --force` but I can't tell who did it from the logs. Is there a way to identify the culprit?

Comment: You could get each member of your team to take a polygraph. Failing that tell them everyone will have to work through their lunch for a week if the culprit doesnt come forward

Comment: Note that you would soon be able to [do a `git push --force` in a more secure way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18505634/6309)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Update Nov. 2018: if you are pushing to a centralized Git repository hosting service like GitHub, *then* you would be able to see who has forced push your branch. But only because GitHub has chosen to surface that event in its GUI.

[image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DsJIVxtU4AAreMW.jpg:large]

See more at "[Find committer of a force push on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53343686/6309)".

---

Original answer 2013:

As I mention in "[Distributed Version Control Systems and the Enterprise - a Good mix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683253/distributed-version-control-systems-and-the-enterprise-a-good-mix/5685757#5685757)", there is no authorization or authentication with Git alone.

You need an [authorization layer](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html) like [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) in order to keep track of who does what. (Gitolite comes with its own audit trail mechanism).

But if your repo is accessible through [file (or local) protocol](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html#Local-Protocol), then you cannot know who forced pushed.

[image: polygraph] <sup>(from [motivationalgenerator.com](http://motivationalgenerator.com/unmoderated-motivational-posters/share/158846), and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygraph))</sup>

Comment: Using bitbucket. No record. Could it be done accidentally with some GUI tool that doesn’t bring up a dialog to warn the user?

Comment: @wcochran I confirm the record I mention above is for GitHub repository only. For BitBucket, a `push --force` can be done from any number of sources, including a simple command line session.

Answer (score 4):

If you are **lucky** enough to use [GitHub](http://github.com) or [GitHub for Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com/home), you can have a look to the [events](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-repository-events) REST API and check who/when **Pushed/Dropped** to the remote refs, example for log4j:

> https://api.github.com/repos/apache/log4j/events