# Issue with git pull master is out of sync with origin master

Tags: git, git-branch, git-pull, git-fetch

These are the sequence of steps I have performed:

1. committed my changes in branch to local master (commit id `dc9afg2k`)
2. `git fetch origin master && git merge origin master`
3. `git checkout master`
4. `git pull` (this pulled all recent changes)
5. `git fetch origin master && git merge origin master`
6. `git reset --hard origin/master`
7. `git checkout branch`
8. `git blog`

   `git reset --hard dc9afg2k` (commit successful)

   `git checkout master`

   `git log` (this was gone back to 2 days ago).

   `git pull` (`master` is not updating with current `origin/master`).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

An out of sync `master` can happen when the remote repo has received a [forced push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15030429/6309) (`git push --force`) which rewrite the history.

If you have done commits of your own on master:

- make a branch (to remember the current master state)
  git branch old_master
- make sure you don't have any private file you need to save.
- [follow this guide](http://ocpsoft.org/tutorials/git/reset-and-sync-local-respository-with-remote-branch/)

That would be:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
git clean -f -d
```

(you can preview the last cleaning steap with a '`-n`' option: `git clean -n -f -d`)

---

Note that `git fetch origin master && git merge origin master` could be a `git pull origin master`: the interest of keeping the two steps separated is to look at the difference between `master` and `origin/master` before the merge.
If you don't make that diff, then a `git pull` is simpler.