# git - Why reset --hard seems to be always needed

Tags: git, synchronization, reset, pull

When working on two workstations (say one from the office, one from home) on the same git project, after committing/pushing from one and trying to pull from the other (say the next day), branch seems always to be out of sync after

git pull --all

and the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907689/issue-with-git-pull-master-is-out-of-sync-with-origin-master) is needed.

Why is that? (I never do a forced push as implied in the above post).

Comment: When you say "out of sync," what do you mean? Could you give an example?

Comment: Different contents in the remote than in the local branch (which tracks the remote!). The local has not incorporated the changes after `git pull --all`. For example I see directories in the remote (when accessing it through the web of github or bbucket) which I do not see locally. These changes were committed when working in my previous workstation (e.g. the day before).

Comment: Hmmm, that is a strange one. You are sure that your local is tracking the remote? When you do `git branch -vv` does it show it as tracking? Does this happen on both of your machines?

Answer (score 2):

The safest way to handle git repositories from getting corrupted due to some dangling heads or forced push is to use the following:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/your_branch
```

`git pull` by default fetches and then merges instead of rebasing.

Difference between merge and rebase can be found here:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/conceptual-overview

What you should do now is remove the repo from both of your workstations(obviously after committing and pushing all the local changes). Clone it again. Create a local tracking branch for 'your_origin_branch'. And follow the above procedure to make changes henceforth.

Comment: Small addition: If you fetch your changes from one workstation, you can also `git pull --ff --ff-only` to "pull && merge --ff-only`. This, of course, does only work if there are no (unpublished) changes in your local repo on the current branch.