# Git branching previous commits

Tags: git, github

I have the following situation.

[image: local repo]

What I wanted to do is the following: reset the `HEAD` to where the `master` is on the picture. Also I have a branch named `backupRestore`. Now I want that branch to end with the commit it is created of. So I want to remove the last two commits : `Merge branch 'master' of github...` and `remotes\origin\master`. And this way reset the `HEAD` to `master` (master on the picture). The problem is that I need to update my github repo, which has different structure (as you can see, `remotes/origin/master` is the `HEAD` on github.

**UPDATE**

After applying the solution my tree looks like this:
[image: Solved issue]

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github/448929#448929) can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nobody pulled from your GitHub repo, and if you don't have any local work in progress:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard master
git push -f -u origin master
git checkout backupRestore
git push -f -u origin backupRestore
```

Then try a:

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative --branches --all
```

And see if the end result looks like what you are describing in your question.

Comment: @Pio it is, indeed, forced. That means you won't be able to tell who did a `push -f` on the upstream repo ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/15030429/6309