# Getting a history of which commits were force pushed

Tags: git, github

Yesterday, we had a member of our team do a `git push --force` inside of our Bitbucket repository.  I am aware of who it was, but I am wondering if it is possible to gather which commits were force pushed into the repository.

The information I am looking for from the git log / history is something like this -

`+ 1951097...9b070f0 tower      -> origin/tower  (forced update)`

I saw this message when I was trying to pull into my local branch and encountered merge conflicts after the force push, but I havent been able to see it anywhere else except that one time.  Is there a place where I can see all of the commits (specifically ones with that `(forced update)` tag next to them?)  Running `Git reflog` and `git log` do not seem to return this information.

I saw this post(which is hilarious) that is similar - [How can I find out who force pushed in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028246/how-can-i-find-out-who-force-pushed-in-git)

Instead of looking for the specific person (like the asker in the previous question), I am just looking for the commits that were pushed into the repo with --force after I clone it locally.  Is this information possible to gather, or am I out of luck?

Thanks.

Comment: If you can access the repository hosted in the server, you can see the reflogs there. Better to implement some access control like "not allow force push".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15030429/6309) was about finding *who* did the forced push, not about what was force-pushed.

If you have access to the server, you should find a trace of the old commits (before the push) with [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

From there, you can infer the new commits which replaced the old branch history.

Note that if you do not have access to the remote server (typically: github.com), you can *still* get the old branch SHA1 (the one *before* the forced push) with the "poor man's reflog", aka the push events ([GitHub Events API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/)).
See "[Does github remember commit IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958418/6309)": look for any recent push events on the right branch: the last one would be the one forced, the previous one would represent the old SHA1 commit.

Comment: Well, yes, except that `core.logAllRefUpdates` defaults to *false* in a bare repository, and most server side repositories are bare. It looks like GitHub remembers more details than just hashes, so that must be done independently.

Comment: @torek Yes, if we are talking about github.com, you will get a lot through the push events.