# Convert pushed git commits into one

Tags: git, project-management, bitbucket, git-reset

I'm using a boilerplate for any new projects I make. However the commits I made in the boilerplate gets through to the new project. How would I go about to simply have an "Intial commit" which includes everything in one commit and removes the old commit history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use rebase command for this

git rebase -i HEAD~N

N is the number of commits you want to meld into one..
And then do a force push..

Answer (score 0):

you could follow the question "[git: how to squash the first two commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598672/git-how-to-squash-the-first-two-commits)", and squash the n-commits on your new repo.
The [script is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2662323/6309), can squash the first commits while replaying the rest of the commits you want to keep in the history of the new repo.

```
git clone boilerplaterepo newrepo
# apply the script for git reset --soft $1 everything
```

The solution uses `git reset --soft`, and is an example of one of the "[Practical uses of `git reset --soft?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203535/practical-uses-of-git-reset-soft/5203843)".

---

If you want a solution based on rebase --interactive (less practical, as it involve a manual step), [don't forget the `--root` option (git 1.7.12)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309391/6309), in order to rebase down to the root commit.

```
 git rebase -i --root
 git push -f
```