# How to combine commits between any two historical commits?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-commit

For example, I have commits as follows (`A..H` are commit hashes):

```
A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H
```

Is there a way I could combine commits between `C` and `G`?

I do not want to use `git rebase -i C`, and manually change all the commits between `C` and `G` from `pick` to `f`,

because commit `F` is "Merge branch 'xxxxxxx' into xxxxxxx", in which there are too many commits, which I need to pick up and change too many `pick`s to `f`.

I have tried [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2662323/4281579) as well, but it requires solving conflicts. I do not think I need solving conflicts as I am not merging from another branch but combine several previous commits together.

Comment: what do you mean with `combine historical commits`. if `A`..`H` are commit-hashes, there is no way to replace `C-G` with `X` and still have `H` on top of that.

Comment: Yep, `A..H` are commit hashes. I think at least by using interactive rebase I can combine and replace `C-G` with `C` and still have `H`.

Comment: If commit `F` really is a *merge* commit (with two or more parents), you cannot combine it this way. In any case you will not *keep* commit `H`, you will *copy* commit `H` to a new copy `H'` that will have a different hash ID.

Comment: So you want to change the history but leave it unchanged?

Comment: @ThibaultD. that's correct. I want to change history but leave as many commits unchanged as possible.

Comment: As torek said, whenever you change a commit X, all the following commits will have to change too. So if you want to group C D E, F will have to change too.