# Squash every commits older than 1 year in a very huge repository and limited resource

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history, squash

I have a 4 years old git repository that starts to become really huge: ~30GO, 60.000 files.  One or two commit are done each day.  I would like to squash every commits older than 1 year into the first commit.  But because of technical issues, I can't just recreate the repo, I have to work with it.  The git version available is 1.7.2.5 (not possible to update).  The disk space is limited to 100go (so only 70go are still available) and the device memory is 4go (19mo of swap, yes MO...), not possible to move the repo on another computer either.

I tried the selected solution on this page [Squash the first two commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598672/squash-the-first-two-commits-in-git), the February 2009 version.  It works until the 'git rebase --onto'.  The git-rebase causes a OutOfMemory error, I am not sure of the cause, I think it's maybe because it tries to play every commits in a single shot.  I am thinking to use git-cherry-pick and playing each commit one at a time, then move master at the top of it.

Is it a good idea? or anyone has a better idea ? thks! :)

Comment: Just increase the memory available to the virtual machine, that might fix the problem with out of memory.

Comment: The physicals settings of the VM are frozen, it's a really old proprietary virtual system.  The only thing I could increase is the disk storage by adding an extra disk.

Comment: `git replace` with `git filter-repo` should solve this and should be much more efficient than git-rebase(1).

Answer (score 0):

before do this make sure that know git functionality
git is (key, value) storage that all SHA1 hash is key and value in binary that stored in `.git/object`

you can see `.git` folder for find large file in this folder but one of git functionality is cleanup and optimize repository that work with `git gc` command

if you have big repository before do anything run this command for find large file with this command :

`git rev-list --objects --all | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype) %(objectname) %(objectsize) %(rest)' | sed -n 's/^blob //p' | sort --numeric-sort --key=2 | cut -c 1-12,41- | $(command -v gnumfmt || echo numfmt) --field=2 --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7 --round=nearest`

in git we never miss anything if you commit large file in git and remove it, this file will remain in the git history(in object folder) and one of the `git gc` work is to gradually remove unnecessary file
you can use

`git gc`

`git gc --aggressive`

`git prune`

for optimize space

Answer (score -1):

It's unlikely that the number of commits is causing the issue, git is very efficient at compressing text files.

The best way to reduce the size of a git repository is to use a tool such as [BFG repo cleaner](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to remove large binary files from your history.

Compiled dependencies such as Nuget packages and Jars should be primarily stored in an artefact repository (not git), the application build process will fetch dependencies at build time.

You can also use [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) to store your binary files in a more transparent way.

Comment: The fact is, there are only text files in the repository, no binary at all.  But I am also thinking about BFG or/and git-filter-branch to remove old and useless files through the whole history.