# Squashing complete history before a certain tag

Tags: git, history, rebase

Following scenario: I have a repo with a large history (migrated from SVN which was used since 2006) and want to push the newer history to an external server.

I have a tag, say `mytag` and want to delete all commits that occurred *before* that tag but want to keep the history that occurred *since* this tag.

I tried to do it like in the accepted answer of [Rebase many commits to one in Git. What am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729924/rebase-many-commits-to-one-in-git-what-am-i-doing-wrong), but this results in endless conflict resolving.

I just want to throw away the history while being able to merge my local repo (that still holds the large history) to the remote repo (with the short history).

How do I achive that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Update: note that in the below I'm assuming that `mytag` only has one parent commit, otherwise it's a bit more complicated.*

First, let's assume that you only have one root commit and that it's `f414f31`.  (If you need to find all the root commits you can do that with [the first command in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006775/git-how-to-reference-the-initial-commit/1007545#1007545).)

To be safe, let's create a new branch for this operation, so your branch `master` is left as it was, just in case the results aren't as you would like.

```
git checkout -b new-master
```

Reset this branch to the root commit:

```
git reset --hard f414f31
```

Now change the working tree and the index to be the same as the commit just before `mytag`:

```
git merge --squash mytag^
```

Then create a commit from the index - if you want to rewrite the root commit, you can do that with `git commit --amend`, but I would prefer to keep one commit in common between your old and new histories, so I'd just do:

```
git commit
```

Now what you need to do is to replay all your work since (and including) `mytag` on top of that commit.  This is what `git rebase` is intended for, but by default it will linearize all the history that you're trying to replay.  If have you many merge commits in the history since `mytag`, that may be the reason that you see many conflicts.

So, if you don't mind the history being linearized and you can fix the conflicts (possibly with the help of `git rerere`) you could just do:

```
git rebase --onto new-master mytag^ master
```

However, if there are merges in that history, and you would prefer to keep them, you could try adding the `-p` (`--preserve-merges`) option, which will try to recreate them:

```
git rebase -p --onto new-master mytag^ master
```

---

You ask a further question in the comments below about the case where you have two root commits.  In that case, you could just pick one of them, and use `git commit --amend` after the squashed merge to create a completely new root commit for the rewritten history.

Comment: @Mark: what if I have two root commits? What would I do with the second one?

Comment: @eckes: I've added to my answer to address that.

Comment: @Mark: that's it. Successfully cut the history of my `master` branch now. But I've left a long living feature branch that was branched off master *after* `mytag`. Do I have to do the same on that feature branch or could I rebase it somehow onto master?

Comment: @eckes: you can rebase that branch directly onto the new master.  Do you want to rebase it onto the tip of your new master branch, or to rebase it onto the corresponding branch point in the rewritten history?

Comment: @eckes: In that case, if we suppose the last commit on your original master before the branch was O and the corresponding commit in the rewritten history is R, you could do `git checkout longfeature`, `git rebase --onto R O longfeature`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rewrite/delete history, then you are looking for [git filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch). Here's a nice [thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/purging-unwanted-history-td1507638.html) that discusses how to remove commits. The $drop variable would be the commit before your mytag.

Comment: the thread looks promising, but doesn't work for me. After doing `git filter-branch` like advised in the thread, my history is still unchanged. It rewrites 401 revisions (those AFTER `mytag`), but I cannot see any difference with `gitk`. Any hints?

Comment: One difference between my repo and the repo used in your provided thread is that I don't have just one branch. Should it also work under that circumstances?

Comment: Hmm yep it should work. This should set the parents to nil for some commits, thus they will be garbagecollected later on when "git gc" is run.

Comment: but this only works for those commits that are direct children of `$drop`, right? I assume that I'll have to take ALL commits that are before `mytag` instead of just `^mytag`. How would I achieve that?

Comment: @eckes: be sure to specify `--tag-name-filter cat -- --all` to act on all branches and tags; then use the steps from the man-page to 'vacuum' your repository (several steps!). In that case, a `rev-list --all` or `log --all` should no longer list the old commits